# ventana modal bootstrap no cierra

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Mi ventana modal no cierra al dar click en el botón de cerrar, anteriormente funcionaba correctamente y ahora ya no cierra,

este es el codigo html del boton cerrar:

```
<div id="modalContractCandidatesPre" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content"> <!-- div que continen toda la ventana modal -->
                <div class="modal-header"> <!-- Header -->
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

y el footer

```
<div class="modal-footer"> <!-- Footer -->
                    <button id="saveContractCandidatePre" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Guardar
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cerrar
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Comment: haz revisado si te sale algún error en la consola ?

Comment: si pero no se muestra ningun error, por eso no se que es lo que este fallando, ayer lo unico que hice agregue unas librerias para dataTable para poner botones de exportar a excel y ocultar culumnas pero no se si sea x eso

Comment: La segunda opción puede ser aplicarle un evento click al botón y que ejecute $("#modalContractCandidatesPre").modal('hide');

Comment: no funciona el evento click

Comment: $("#modalCommentsCandidatesPre").off("click");
       $("#modalCommentsCandidatesPre").on("click","#modalComents",closeModalComents);
       function closeModalComents(){
        alert("se dio click en cerrar ventana");
       }

Comment: Prueba quitando el método off() no estoy seguro si puede intervenir para los hijos de un elemento

Comment: ya intente con $("#modalContractCandidatesPre").modal('hide'); asignando un evento click al boton y si me funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Genial, te lo publicaré como respuesta !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es extraño que no te cierre la modal con el botón pasándole el atributo `data-dismiss="modal"` pero eso no es problema ya que podemos "forzar" a que la modal se cierre por medio de JavaScript:

```js
$(".cerrarModal").click(function(){
  $("#modalContractCandidatesPre").modal('hide')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContractCandidatesPre">
  Abrir modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalContractCandidatesPre" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cerrarModal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Título modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cerrarModal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta llevaba mucho tiempo buscando algo como estoy  me ha servido a pesar de ser tan vieja la pregunta cuya respuesta es totalmente valida, saludos!

Comment: Excelente justo lo que andaba buscando, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La causa es la siguiente:

```
data-keyboard="false"
```

este valor impide que se cierre con la tecla `escape`

```
data-backdrop="static"
```

este valor impide que se cierre cuando haces `click` fuera del modal